# Нижний Новгород, но — нижегородский

Tags: топонимика

Если речь о городе Нижний Новгород, то, по идее, нужно говорить "нижненовгородский", но почему-то говорят "нижегородский". Это сделано для краткости или есть какая-то еще причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не думаю, что употреблять слово "сделано" тут правомерно. Вряд ли тут есть чья-то воля. Скорее всего в нижегородец, нижегородский закрепилось стихийно сложившееся употребление. Не стоит также ориентироваться на краткость: аналоги, например, для Архангельска (архангелогородец, архангелогородский) никак краткостью не объясняются, разве что простотой употребления.
На мой взляд ларчик может открываться просто. В быту "город Нижний Новгород" стягивается до "город Нижний". Отсюда и рассматриваемая форма прилагательного. Аналогично для упомянутого Архангельска. До относительно недавнего времени его называли "городом Архангелов". 
//---
Меня сейчас вот поправили. Не "город архангелов", а вполне конкретного архангела Михаила. Город был основан вблизи Михаило-Архангельского монастыря. Остальное в силе.